# Django DateField form generates None in cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, datefield

After selecting dates from DateField's form in django and hitting submit button, is_valid() succeeds, but cleaned_data shows None. 
Does anyone know what is the issue? Thanks

forms.py

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
    day_from = forms.DateField(label=u'Začiatok obdobia', input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], 
        required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
    day_to = forms.DateField(label=u'Koniec obdobia', input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], 
        required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
```

views.py

```
def dp_list(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form_date = DateForm(request.POST)
    if form_date.is_valid():
        date_from = form_date.cleaned_data['day_from']
        date_to = form_date.cleaned_data['day_to']
        print(date_from, date_to, type(date_from), type(date_to))
        print(form_date.cleaned_data)
```

datelist.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form | materializecss:"s4"}}
     <span class="align-bottom">
         <input class="btn primary-btn pink" type="submit" value="Zobraz">
     </span>
</form>
```

Output of prints in console:

```
> ## None None class 'NoneType' class 'NoneType'
> ## {'day_from': None, 'day_to': None}
```

Comment: Is that the whole of your form code? And what data did you enter into the form when you submitted?

Comment: Looks like a front-end issue to me - your fields might not be properly populated. Do you have any js date selector ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I don't use any js date picker. @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 0):

This happens because one of the fields isn't cleaned. You can confirm which field by doing an `else` and `print(form_date.cleaned_data)`, the `print`'s should have one less field.